# How to prevent Visual Studio from compiling solution after I exit debug mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, build

Visual Studio builds the entire solution when I exit debug mode.

This is very annoying as the solution contains 42 projects (ASP.NET MVC, IIS hosted WCF, Silverlight apps and others) and the build process locks Visual Studio for aprox. 30 seconds.

What causes Visual Studio to do a full rebuild of the solution? Is there a setting that I can turn on to determine the root of the problem?

Comment: It doesn't happen every time, tough. About 10% of the start-debug-exit work fine, whereas about 90% of the time I get above behaviour.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't comment on this question any more, or pick an answer - I have moved on to a different place.

Comment: God I hate this behavior!  Happens everytime I leave a source file modified during a debugging session, then exit debugging.  VC immediately attempts to compile my changes and a significant portion of the time crashes (because my changes were incoherent, and the compiler seems to have multithreading lock/race issues.

Answer (score 2):

Are you editing the source code during debugging?

VS does a "temporary"* compile in these cases to let you carry on running the program. Once you exit debug mode it knows this and can do a full rebuild of the project.

If you're going to do further changes then this build is a waste of time. Have you looked at the options on Tools > Options > Debugging > Edit and Continue? There's an option called *Relink code changes after debugging* and it's enabled by default. Try turning that off.

* this is the wrong term, but I can't remember the correct one at the moment.

Comment: no code changes. it even happens when I hit start, then stop after the website's start page has fully loaded in the browser.

Comment: @o_o - You could try turning that option off anyway - if nothing else it would eliminate it as a possibility. *This is the sound of me clutching at straws!*

Comment: @o_o - OK, I'm completely stumped. Don't take this the wrong way, but without seeing exactly what options you choose, what steps you take and exactly what happens during your debug session, I can't think what could be causing this behaviour.  Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Today I disabled whole "*Edit and Continue*" option and annoying recompilation hasn't occured since then.

Comment: I like being able to edit & continue.  If that's what I want.  It's just ext & auto-recompile I hate with a passion!

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to *Tools* → *Options* → *Projects and Solutions* → *Build and Run*.
2. Enable *Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run*.

Comment: I have this checked off.  But it does it anyway :(  VS 2010 SP 1

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Edit and Continue and try turning off 'Relink code changes after debugging'

Answer (score 1):

1- Go to Tools → Options → Projects and Solutions → Build and Run

2- Enable-> Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run.

3- On Run , when projects are out of date

```
select -> prompt to build 
          or never build (probably you don't want to do this)
```