# Visual Studio 2008 compiling when I exit debug mode (with a vengeance)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have a solution at work (with 33 projects) that insists on compiling the whole thing when I exit debug mode. It's extremely irritating as the IDE is unresponsive while at it.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096824/), but I've already completely *disabled Edit-and-Continue*. Also, it does this when I don't make any changes.

I have a fairly vanilla VS2008 (Team System) installation. We run Code Style Enforcer and use Team Foundation Server. The project is a collection of C# WCF projects, library assemblies, a web app and some deployment projects.

Any ideas? It didn't do this up until sometime last week, but I didn't change anything. Some colleague might have changed something in the solution, but I still can't imagine what would cause this.

Comment: Is it wanting to compile because you made changes?  Maybe I don't understand the question, but if you make changes, you should recompile; if you don't make changes, no recompilation should be necessary.  I don't understand what debug mode has to do with it; can you please clarify?

Comment: @apollodude217: it recompiles, even when no changes have been made. I have no idea what debugging has to do with it, but Visual Studio triggers the build upon pressing the stop button... I just interrupt the build nowadays :)

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem, sometimes it compiles everything 5 times.

The only way we have been able to stop it, is by running through the program and stopping it by closing the browser.

If you stop it by pressing the stop debug button, the compiling starts.